Импорт модулей в Java
Как импортировать модуль в проекте Java в IntelliJ IDEA (с иcпользованием Maven) из другого модуля, используя Module from Existing Sources в меню File. Например, нужно в проекте, имеющем в основном классе Main приведённый ниже примитивный код, импортировать из модуля, созданного программой по умолчанию, в другой, вновь созданный модуль, который будет называться, например, module2, и будет находиться, например, в корневой директории проекта, функционал исходного модуля.
Структура папок проекта до импорта такая:
TestModules
   |__src/
      |__ main/
      |   |__ java/
      |       |__ org.example/
      |           |__ Main <- Основной класс
  |__ pom.xml 

Интересует именно импорт модуля, а не создание нового модуля, т.к. в дальнейшем планируется, используя этот инструмент, импортировать в проект функционал из других проектов, в качестве модулей, а в них много папок и переписывать их вручную очень трудозатратно и занимает много времени.
package org.example;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("ЭТО ИСХОДНЫЙ МОДУЛЬ");
    }
}


как задать хороший вопрос. начните с заголовка, который должен содержать краткую суть вопроса, а не то, что там сейчас написано.

Чтобы импортировать модуль из существующих источников, нужно выполнить следующие действия:

Импорт модуля из существующих источников:
Используйте эти шаги для импорта проекта как модуля, если проект получен из внешней модели или если вы хотите создать модуль из существующего исходного кода, который не обязательно является экспортированным проектом.

В главном меню перейдите в Файл | Создать | Модуль из существующих источников.

Выберите каталог, в котором находятся ваши источники, библиотеки и другие ресурсы, и нажмите Открыть.

В открывшемся диалоговом окне выберите Создать модуль из существующих источников, если вы хотите создать новый модуль из существующего исходного кода.

В противном случае выберите Импорт проекта из внешней модели, выберите внешнюю модель, которую использует проект, и следуйте инструкциям мастера.



